# node traverse using cheerio js

Tags: jquery, html, cheerio

I have something like this (html code) fetch with `snekfetch`

```
<div class="entry-content">
<h4>today's date etc etc</h4>
    <h3>category name 1</h3>
    <p>
        <img class="aligncenter" src="img_1.png" alt="" />
    </p>
    <div></div>
    <p>
        <img class="aligncenter" src="img_2.png" alt="" />
    </p>
    <div></div>
    <h4>today's date etc etc</h4>
    <h3>category name 2</h3>
    <p>
        <img class="aligncenter" src="img_3.png" alt="" />
    </p>
    <div></div>
    <h4>today's date etc etc</h4>
    <h3>category name 3</h3>
    <p>
        <img class="aligncenter" src="img_4.png" alt="" />
    </p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

My purpose of using cheerio is to extract the img src, I manage to extract the img src but the problem is, I need to categorize them in name such as `img_1.png` and `img_2.png` belongs to `<h3>` tag category name 1 and so on.

I would to store them in an array such as

```
 name: category 1
 src: img_1.png
 name: category 1
 src: img_2.png
```

and so on for all other category name with the img src under those `<h3>` tag

also this result from snekfetch can be random which means category name 1 sometimes have 3-4 images instead of 2 possible even 1.

So I would like to use cheerio to detect them dynamic but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
let $ = cheerio.load(html);
let currentElement, data = {};

$(".entry-content").find("h3").each(function () {
    data[$(this).text()] = [];

    currentElement = $(this);

    while(currentElement.next().length && currentElement.next().prop("tagName").indexOf("H") === -1) {
        if (currentElement.next().find("img").length > 0) {
            data[$(this).text()].push(currentElement.next().find("img").first().attr("src"));
        }

        currentElement = currentElement.next();
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this, but the logic should be pretty much okay, incase it isn't I will be glad to help

**EDIT** I have created an object where the keys are the categories which have an array of the pics, its more flexible that way but you can adjust it to your liking or just ask if you get stuck

Comment: i think h3 being used as loop will be hard on this case cause snekFetch do get whole html page out with other h3 inside. I just plug that html code out as some parts/

Comment: then use `$(".entry-content").find("h3")` instead of just `$("h3")`

Comment: tested the code and got this error
(node:2201) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Hey am sorry, i haven't used jquery in a long time, am used to vanilla JS, its supposed to be `currentElement.next().prop("tagName").indexOf("H")`

Comment: getting this error now (node:4290) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure that error comes from the code above, because I didn't use any `name` property in my code, try debugging by commenting parts of the code, if its from my code, I'll review it and provide more help

Comment: yea is from your code, i commented out yours and is working fine. I commented out some part of mine and leave yours and still hitting that error.

Comment: commented your while loop, not giving any errors anymore but i can only fetch 1 of the img url only for each h3.

Comment: Am debugging in my browser console and edited the while condition to `currentElement.next().length && currentElement.next().tagName.indexOf("H") === -1` and it worked, try that on your end

Comment: while (currentElement.next().length && currentElement.next().prop("tagName").indexOf("H") === -1) { 

this is working for me, thanks alot. maybe you can edit your code above with this

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: possible if you can explain to me about the while loop what is for?
while(currentElement.next().length && currentElement.next().prop("tagName").indexOf("H") === -1)

Comment: Since the images are in the same level as the categories and the categories and other metadata are in title tags (I saw h3 and h4), so we go to the next element until there is no more next element (`currentElement.next().length`) or the next element is a title element (`currentElement.next().prop("tagName").indexOf("H") === -1`) i.e. only loop if there is a next element and that element is not a title element, then we exit the loop and go to the next h3 tag. I hope its clear enough